Writing to delta table using WriteSerializable, IllegalArgumentException
I'm using pyspark 3.3.2 and have the corresponding spark version installed. For my unit tests, I create my sparksession like so:

Using delta-core 2.3.0, which I believe should be compatible (https://docs.delta.io/3.1.0/releases.html). When I write a dataframe like this:
    output_df.write.partitionBy("col1", "col2")
    .format("delta")
    .mode("append")
    .option("delta.isolationLevel", "WriteSerializable")
    .option("mergeSchema", "true")
    .save(self.output_path)

I get the error:
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: delta.isolationLevel must be Serializable
The code itself runs fine on databricks. This test that fails runs in the databricksruntime docker container https://hub.docker.com/layers/databricksruntime/python/12.2-LTS/images/sha256-3138f5dcad8b9997bda0b27623d46ed3f380c5ad5f4a8ad8ce122831c916e793?context=explore
What am I doing wrong?

I believe the problem is that isolationLevel WriteSerializable is only available on databricks, and not in our test-pipeline, where the open-source delta lake is used, based on this code: https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/d330cb18e390b8c431697436e9828659be51b26e/spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/DeltaConfig.scala#L660
